# Split list into key-values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery I have scraped a text-string that looks like this:

```
Org nr: 9 111222-3333
Firma: Company Name
Kommun: Botkyrka
Postadress: SomeRoad 84, 147 52 TUMBA,
Verksamhet: Bolaget ska bedriva taxiverksamhet.
Innehavare: 11111111-1111 Surname, Name Name, SomeRoad 84, 147 52 TUMBA,
```

It can contain any number of rows and have any keys and any values. they are always separated by a colon.

I want to save theese as key-values to an object and am not sure what approach is best. Should I do a regex? In that case, how do I do a foreach in regex?

Comment: this is doable in Regex easily, however It is difficult to separate the keys from values when they are side by side as nothing appears to be separating them.

Comment: nevermind now is it separated by line break;

Comment: Also, please be careful when posting personal data in your question, please :)

Comment: Split over line breaks, loop, split at first `": "`

Comment: @PaulS. How do you split at linebreak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehuem..

```
var text = '...';
var obj = {};
var rows = text.split('\n');
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var arr = rows.split(':');
    obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Now when it's written, I see I'm too late.. and the regex seems to be better, but this might be easier to read...

Answer (score 1):

[***There you go :(jsbin)***](http://jsbin.com/ovulis/2/edit)

```
var t="Org nr: 9 670220-5458\n\      // you said you have linebreaks
Firma: Shamel Taxi\n\
Kommun: Botkyrka\n\
Postadress: Grytstigen 84, 147 52 TUMBA,\n\
Verksamhet: Bolaget ska bedriva taxiverksamhet.\n\
Innehavare: 19670220-5458 Fathalla, Shamel Said, Grytstigen 84, 147 5\2 TUMBA,";

var g=t.split(/[\n\u0085\u2028\u2029]|\r\n?/gim);

var o={};

for (var i=0;i<g.length;i++)
{
  var g2= g[i].split(':');

  o[g2[0].trim()]=g2[1];
}
console.log(o)
```

result

```
[object Object] {
  Firma: " Shamel Taxi",
  Innehavare: " 19670220-5458 Fathalla, Shamel Said, Grytstigen 84, 147 5 TUMBA,",
  Kommun: " Botkyrka",
  Org nr: " 9 670220-5458",
  Postadress: " Grytstigen 84, 147 52 TUMBA,",
  Verksamhet: " Bolaget ska bedriva taxiverksamhet."
}
```

Comment: Lol! Exactly the same answer.. :)

Comment: @LeonardPauli yep....:-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you would use the following:

```
([^:]+): (.*)
```

Backreference group 1 is the key and backreference group 2 is the value.

**JS:**

```
result = subject.match(/([^:]+): (.*)/g);
```

You then need to just access the groups and you have all the stuff you need.

Comment: I think the string-split solution in the comments seem more practical, thanks for an extensive answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick, you can split the string by ':' first and then for each component starting from 2nd element, get the last part separated by space and assume this as the name of the next key-value pair, this is my try:

```
var string = "Org nr: 9 670220-5458 Firma: Shamel Taxi Kommun: Botkyrka Postadress: Grytstigen 84, 147 52 TUMBA, Verksamhet: Bolaget ska bedriva taxiverksamhet. Innehavare: 19670220-5458 Fathalla, Shamel Said, Grytstigen 84, 147 52 TUMBA,;"

splited = string.split(':');
list = [splited[0]]
for (x in splited) {
    if (x == 0) continue;
    var t = splited[x].split(' ');
    list.push(t.slice(0, t.length - 1).join(' ').trim());
    list.push(t[t.length - 1].trim());
}

result = {}
for (var i = 0; i < list.length - 1;) {
    result[list[i]] = list[i + 1];
    i += 2;
}

console.log(result);
```

this is the result

```
Firma: "Shamel Taxi"
Innehavare: "19670220-5458 Fathalla, Shamel Said, Grytstigen 84, 147 52"
Kommun: "Botkyrka"
Org nr: "9 670220-5458"
Postadress: "Grytstigen 84, 147 52 TUMBA,"
Verksamhet: "Bolaget ska bedriva taxiverksamhet."
```

Again, you can play with this code and since the input is too random, this is the best that I can give you.